# Use variable to find xpath selenium not working

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am working on web automation with selenium and I need to find an element with the xpath. This by itself is not a problem but the code needs to run multiple times and when it does that the HTML xpath changes. This is also not a problem. I have used simple math to get the new xpath every time.

The xpathes look like this

```
1. run: '//*[@id="input-text-3"]'
2. run: '//*[@id="input-text-5"]'
3. run: '//*[@id="input-text-7"]' etc.
```

I solved this problem using this code:

```
y = 1
#Corme browser already defined and on website 
while True:
    mathop1 = y*2 + 1
    xxpath = ""'//*[@id="input-text-' + str(mathop1) + '"]'""
    xxpath1 = "'" + str(xxpath) + "'"
    print(xxpath1)    
    Bezeichnung = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xxpath1)
    Bezeichnung.send_keys(file1name)
    y = y + 1
```

What this does is that every time the program loops it updates y so the xpath will be correct. I tried using the output from xxpath1 to find the element like you normally would and it works fine however as soon as I use the variable it does not work. Specifically, the problem is this I can't use the variable.

```
Bezeichnung = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xxpath1)
```

why does this not work?

Comment: "I can't use this variable" -- what do you mean exactly? Are you getting some error?

Comment: yes I am getting an error but the variable is defined

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I'm getting this error specifically :   File "c:/Users/bodig/Desktop/Advanced adlo builder.py", line 303, in <module>
    Bezeichnung = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xxpath1)

Comment: Also this: TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.

Comment: You haven't pasted the error text. Please add that and paste it in your question.

Also, what are you trying to do when you change `xxpath` like this: `xxpath1 = "'" + str(xxpath) + "'"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I guess you have to put a wait condition there.
Also, I do not understand why are you using so much strings inside string and converting string to string again, so I removed that

```
y = 1
#Corme browser already defined and on website 
while True:
    mathop1 = y*2 + 1
    xxpath = '//*[@id="input-text-{}"]'.format(mathop1)
    Bezeichnung = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xxpath)))
    Bezeichnung.send_keys(file1name)
    y = y + 1
```

Comment: I have tried the code but it still does not work. Now it gives me this error: 
ine 301, in <module>
    Bezeichnung = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xxpath")))

Comment: What error? timeout? or element not found?

Comment: Timeout I think this is what it says: line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Seems that the `xpath` expression is not correct. I guess there is no `iframe` there? Since it can also be the issue.

Comment: I don't quite understand? What do you mean by IFrame?

Comment: What you get there without the expected conditions as I suggested, just simply `Bezeichnung = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xxpath)` ?

Comment: But that's what I had at the beginning. Il try it anyway

Comment: Yeah it does not work this is the error it gave me SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id="input-text-3]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Sure, there is a syntax error in that xpath. Please use my xpath `xxpath = '//*[@id="input-text- + str(mathop1)"]'`

Comment: your path does not work. from what I understand the str(mathop1) needs to not be part of the "". I get an Unable to locate element error but that is understandable as there is no element called //*[@id="input-text- + str(mathop1)"]

Comment: I just tested the output by printing the xxpath and it gives me the right path but doesn't the xpath need to be like this '//*[@id="input-text-3]' to work ? rn it outputs the same thing without the ''

Comment: OK, I think I know what is the problem, please see the updated answer.

Comment: GREAT it worked. Thank you very much. Btw it didn't work the first time but all I had to do was edit the coda a bit like this: Bezeichnung = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xxpath))) and it worked

Comment: You are right! It's quite difficult to write code not inside the IDE :)
The main issue here was formatting the string with parameter. Well, my Python is not really good...